# Выполнение функции с интервалами в 3 секунды

Tags: javascript

Написал функцию. Хочу, чтобы она 20 раз вызвала другую функцию с интервалами в 3 секунды, но мой код почему-то не работает. Мало того, после начала выполнения страница повисает и может съесть всю оперативную память. После чего она успешно закрывается от нехватки памяти. Что я делаю не так?

```
function searchParser(id) {
    var all_data = {},
        local_data;
    var iteration = 20;
    while(iteration > 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            worker(id);
            iteration--;
            console.log(iteration);
        }, 3000);
    }
};
```

Comment: я б тоже от такого бы съёжился в уголочке и дрожал от страха)) ... Достаточно `setInterval` с проверкой `if` внутри без всяких `while`........ и я не вижу где тут вызывается другая функция

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ой, функцию стёр случайно при табуляции. А что не так-то с setTimeout и while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запускаем интервал. Когда он достигнет нуля - убиваем.

P.S. Я тут в `worker` передаю значение итерации, а не id, для наглядности. Но не суть

```js
function searchParser(id) {
  var all_data = {},
      local_data;
  var iteration = 4;

  var interval = setInterval(() => {
    worker(iteration);
    iteration--;

    if (iteration == 0)
      clearInterval(interval);
  }, 1000);
};

function worker(iteration) {
  console.log('iteration is: ' + iteration);
}

searchParser(666);
```

Comment: А убивать интервал обязательно? Я вот параллельно с вашим ответом на вопрос накодил такую вот конструкцию: `setInterval(() => {
    if(iteration > 0) {
     console.log(worker(id));
     iteration--;
    }
   }, 3000);` Вроде работает, и выполняется ровно 20 раз.

Comment: а вы за "if" console.log('hehe'); добавьте )

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, на самом деле это вывод в консоль выводится 20 раз, а сам таймер продолжает выполняться каждый три секунды и каждый раз проверяет значение iteration. Если ты поменяешь значение этой переменной после 20 итерации, увидишь, что вывод продолжится

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin дело в том, что интервал продолжит свою работу и будет дальше висеть фоном на странице и выполнять задачу. Он просто будет до `if` доходить и выходит...... вот банально запусти до `if` еще один вывод в консоль `var iteration = 4;
setInterval(() => { 
 console.log('yo');
 if(iteration > 0) {   
   console.log(iteration); 
    iteration--; 
  } 
}, 1000);` ......... поэтому убивать интервал обязательно